# Understanding precedence of minor modes keymaps

Tags: keymap, minor-mode

I would like to understand when keymaps of minor modes get "applied" and how do they get applied exactly? In particular, is there a way to see a list of a active minor-mode maps? I know I can look the list of active minor-modes and check which of them has a keymap, but I am looking for a deeper understanding of the mechanism).

One reason I want to understand this is to figure out what happens when I have multiple minor modes mapping the same key sequence. Which one gets precedence and how can I influence this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
minor-mode-map-alist is a variable defined in `C source code'.

Documentation:
Alist of keymaps to use for minor modes.
Each element looks like (VARIABLE . KEYMAP); KEYMAP is used to read
key sequences and look up bindings if VARIABLE's value is non-nil.
If two active keymaps bind the same key, the keymap appearing earlier
in the list takes precedence.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688860/324105 might also help.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I couldn't find that question here. I will mark my question as a duplicate. UPDATE: Wasn't able to since the question is not on Emacs StackExchange.

Comment: " In addition, portions of text in the buffer can specify their own keymaps,
which override all other keymaps." (emacs manual, 49.3.3). Not sure how this should be interpreted.

Comment: @Muihlinn There's a fairly substantial array of keymaps which are checked in priority order.  This question was only about minor modes.  https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs#keymap-lookup-order is a good article on the more general subject.

Comment: A question here can't/shouldn't be closed because it is a duplicate of one on another Stack Exchange site.  On the other hand, we shouldn't duplicate questions across sites - e.g., it wouldn't be a good idea to look for questions on S.O. to duplicate here with new questions. Bottom line: you can *delete* your question here, as it is a duplicate of an SO question. There's no requirement to do that, though.